# CSS the autosuggest results of my search field are displayed under a banner

Tags: css, joomla

I have a Joomla website based on Yootheme's Sync template.

I have my search module which display auto suggest result when visitor start to type characters in search field.

But these auto suggest results are not displayed properly because I published the search module inside a tab module.

See screenshot:
http://prntscr.com/3kwpmf

### This is the CSS of the result:

```
.searchbox .results {
    top: 49px;
    width: 300px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #f4f4f4);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #f4f4f4);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f7f7f7, #f4f4f4);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f7f7f7, #f4f4f4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0px 1px 0 #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
```

---

Is there someone who can help me to fix that?

Comment: Can you post live URL link?

Comment: Try adding a clearfix to the tab content element

Answer (score 0):

Set to position relative and retrieve any height on the wrapper if you want to put inside the box, if you want to overlap set to position: absolute and z-index 999

Answer (score -1):

set:

```
z-index:100
```

or a higher value than your tab module.

Comment: This will simply make the results overlap. It won't change the tab content element height based on the child element